How to convert a curl get request with json data payload into a linear URL string suitable for a browser?
A concrete example:
I send the following command from my PC's console to my web cam at 12.34.56.78, and it works as desired (this cause the web cam to play some audio signal):
curl -X GET 'http://12.34.56.78/api.cgi?user=admin&password=123456' -d '[{"cmd":"AudioAlarmPlay","action":0,"param":{"channel": 0,"alarm_mode":"times","times":1}}]'

Now I want to use this command in a configurable client so that this command will be sent out upon press of a certain button on the GUI.
This client app is configurable in that I can specify a URL string  (i.e. http GET command in text format) inside a text config file that will be sent out when the GUI button is pressed.
Now what string should I write in that config file?!?
Obviously, the curl program will internally generate some text string and then send that one on the http protocol to node 12.34.56.78 (=my web cam). But how exactly(!) does this look like? The config file does not understand curl, it only undertands "linear" URL text strings.
Hope I could make myself clear, and I hope somebody can help me.

More concretely, the config file is an XML file and the http string after "h t t p://12.34.56.78" is specified between two XML tags, like:
/HereIsTheString
So in this example,upon button click the client would send out
"h t t p://12.34.56.78/HereIsTheString" (without the blanks inside http of course)

So the question is: What exactly does the string "HereIsTheString" have to be, such that the web cam 12.34.56.78 receives the same as for the curl command in the OP?

By using -d parameter you are asking curl to make a HTTP POST Request.
And currently it is impossible to make HTTP POST Request with browser address bar.

Short recap on HTTP: HTTP is a text-based communication protocol of the application layer in the OSI model. It is therefore responsible for transferring the actual user data at a very abstract level. Communication follows the request-response principle. The server generates a suitable response for each request, provided that the request contains the necessary information.
It is obvious that the destination of the request must be defined, which is done via a globally unique ID, the URI (Uniform Resource Identifier), in your case more precisely the URL (Uniform Resource Locator). As each endpoint often supports several actions (e.g. retrieving and deleting data), the HTTP access method must also be specified for each request.
Your Situation: You are using cURL, a client for HTTP requests. The program creates your request from your parameters and a few technical details and sends it off.
curl -X GET 'http://12.34.56.78/api.cgi?user=admin&password=123456' \
     -d '[{"cmd":"AudioAlarmPlay","action":0,"param":{"channel": 0,"alarm_mode":"times","times":1}}]'

Let's break down the command:

-X GET defines GET ("Transfer a current representation of the target resource.") as our HTTP access method.
http://12.34.56.78/api.cgi?user=admin&password=123456 Is the destination address. At this point it should be noted that login data is passed as a query parameter, a catastrophic vulnerability. You should strongly consider using the appropriate HTTP authentication mechanisms.
-d ... defines the request body, which contains the information required by the server to fulfill the request.

Your questions

This client app is configurable in that I can specify a URL string (i.e. http GET command in text format) inside a text config file that will be sent out when the GUI button is pressed.

If you follow a link or enter it in your browser, the GET method is used by default, as according to the specification this must not call any actions or changes on the server side (idempotence). Test whether your URI works by simply calling it  via the URL bar in the browser. Note that no custom user data is transferred, if you do it this way (When it comes to calling actions, methods such as POST are typically used). However, this corresponds to the same real-world situation as in your application.

Now what string should I write in that config file?!?
Obviously, the curl program will internally generate some text string and then send that one on the http protocol to node 12.34.56.78 (=my web cam). But how exactly(!) does this look like? The config file does not understand curl, it only undertands "linear" URL text strings.

Since HTTP is a text protocol, you are right in assuming that a text is generated here. But don't confuse the URL (part of a request) with the request itself. We are talking about a part-whole relationship here. You can use the -v argument to switch to verbose out, which will look similar to this:
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Age: 44040
< Cache-Control: max-age=604800
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2024 07:58:43 GMT
< Etag: "3147526947"
< Expires: Wed, 01 May 2024 07:58:43 GMT
< Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
< Server: ECAcc (nyd/D121)
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Cache: HIT
< Content-Length: 1256
<

But after all: As I've described above, you are trying to perform a complete action with a fraction of the necessary information. You will need more than the URL information to trigger this action (you have passed said data with -d).
Hacky solution
Build a proxy that you can address with minimal information and that then subsequently executes the actual request. Roughly sketched:

You press your button. The application calls http://mylocalhost/mediator without any payload data.
The mediator (at http://mylocalhost/mediator) calls the actual handler at http://12.34.56.78/api.cgi. As this is a separate request, it can be made as complex as you like.
The target (http://12.34.56.78/api.cgi) does some action.

